# Webpack - Folder Access Outside Application Folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, configuration

I have code base, the folder structure for which looks like this :

```
|- build\
|- node_modules\
|- apps\
|--- app_no_1\
|----- index.js
|- src\
|--- modules\
|----- form-login\
|------- Form.jsx
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
....
```

The `app_no_1\` folder holds the index file for its React app. However, the modules are sat within the `src\` folder. When I import the component from the `src` directory into the app, I get the error:

```
bundle.js:41448 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // );
```

Is there some webpack configuration option I am missing which is required for access to files outside the app's folder? My `webpack.config.js` is this:

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'apps'),
  appAthenaTrader: path.join(__dirname, 'apps/athenaTrader'),
  appAthenaFinancier: path.join(__dirname, 'apps/athenaFinancier'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  modules: path.join(__dirname, 'src/modules')
};

const common = {
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modules: PATHS.modules
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [PATHS.modules, 'node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Satoshi Ltd - Athena'
    })
  ]
};

const generateEntry = env => {
  const entryVariable = {
    entry: {
      app: ''
    }
  };
  if (env.app === 'athena-trader') {
    entryVariable.entry.app = PATHS.appAthenaTrader;
  } else if (env.app === 'athena-financier') {
    entryVariable.entry.app = PATHS.appAthenaFinancier;
    // } else ...
  }
  return entryVariable;
};

const devServer = {
  devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only',
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};

const generateConfig = env => {
  const entry = generateEntry(env);
  if (env.profile === 'development') {
    return merge(common, entry, devServer);
  }
  return merge(common, entry);
};

module.exports = generateConfig(process.env);
```

I should note that when the folder is brought inside the `app_no_1`, the app functions fine, i.e. it is able to execute the component & display it. However, the above folder structure is not being accepted for the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your babel-loader configuration. Webpack is complaining that it doesn't know how to parse your files (I'm assuming it's JSX).

In your configuration, you have:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      // ...
    ]
```

`include` tells webpack to use `babel-loader` on any files located inside `PATHS.app`. When it looks at your files located in `PATHS.modules`, it doesn't use `babel-loader`. This is when webpack shows that `Module parse failed` error.

To fix this, you can update your `include` value to something like this:

```
include: [PATHS.app, PATHS.modules]
```

An alternative is to use `exclude` instead of `include`.

```
// assuming you want to only ignore node_modules
exclude: /node_modules/
```

I also made a barebones example of this on [Github](https://github.com/newyork-anthonyng/webpack-include-test).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. You are a genius! This was one of those 'duh' moments...